# Passing username to url in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, http, url

I am developing a site in PHP that allows users to sign up and enter in some information, and I would like to give each user a unique URL. When the user logs in to his profile, I want JUST the username to be passed to the URL (like `www.mysite.com/profile.php?user=username`) in order to rewrite it later. However, I'm using the `$_POST` method, and I'm concerned if I use `$_GET` while logging in the password will be  passed to the URL as well. What should I do?

Comment: You tell what parameters to pass into `$_GET` and `$_POST`.. So don't pass the users password into the `$_GET` global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't really be a problem doing this. You could simply use a `POST` method that points to a URL with a `GET` parameter.

So you make a `POST` request to:

```
www.mysite.com/profile.php?user={$username}
```

This way the user variable in the URL doesn't need to be used in the authentication.
Consider this for a simplistic example:

```
<form method="post" action="/profile.php?username=hasan">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="hasan" />
  <input type="text" name="password" value="********" />
</form>
```

The URL you are posting to doesn't have to be hard coded either - you could always dynamically add the user name before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

On the link to or redirection you can add

```
<a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $php_variable ?>">Link to the profile</a>
```

and after you read it (in php file) with `$_GET['user']`

Answer (score 0):

Since the authentication presumably happens in a separate script, e.g. `login.php`, it's just a matter of appending the username to the profile URL when redirecting upon successful login.

```
header('Location: profile.php?username='.$username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lix's answer is best and is what you *should* be doing, but assuming you don't have a login.php and for some strange reason want to go straight to profile.php?user to login, you can use this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#theForm").submit(function() {
            $(this).attr("action", $(this).attr("action") + $("#usernameInput").val());
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And your form looks something like:

```
<form action="http://www.mysite.com/profile.php?user=" method="post" id="theForm">
    <input type="text" name="usernameInput" id="usernameInput">
    <input type="password" name="passwordInput" id="passwordInput">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

And then your action will change to the inputted username upon submit. But still, you should have an intermediary login.php that redirects to profile.php?user.